# Proof of convergence of Thomae-like function

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\ 1 & x=0 \\ 1 / x & x \in \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(x)$ converges as $x$ approaches $a$ if and only if $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

---

Only considering the converse case, so far I've written

$(\Leftarrow)$ Case 1: Let $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$, and let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $f(a) = 0$ and $x \neq a$; therefore there exists $\epsilon_0$ so that
$$0<\epsilon_0<|x-a|<\delta$$
Let $\epsilon_0 = 1/\epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Then
$$0<\frac{1}{\epsilon}<|x-a|<\delta$$
In particular, $x > 1/\epsilon$ and so
$$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{x} &< \epsilon \\ \left| \frac{1}{x} - 0 \right| &< \epsilon \\ \left| f(x) - f(a) \right| &< \epsilon \end{align}$$
whenever $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.

Case 2: Let $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Then for $\epsilon > 0$
$$ \begin{align} \left| f(x) - f(a) \right| &< \epsilon \\ \left| 0 - 0 \right| &< \epsilon \\ 0 &< \epsilon \end{align}$$
whenever $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$, which is true since $\epsilon > 0$.

Therefore if $a \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)$ converges as $x$ approaches $a$.

---

The working for Case 1 is pretty much all I could think of and it looks completely wrong to me so I'd appreciate some thoughts, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to show is not true. For instance, $f$ is not continuous at $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$: indeed, $f(\sqrt{2}) = 0$. By density of rational numbers, there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{r_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $\sqrt{2}$, and by continuity of the inverse function on nonzero numbers, $\frac{1}{r_n} \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\neq 0$. It follows that $f(r_n) \not \to f(\sqrt{2})$, and $f$ is not continuous at $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So just to confirm, by the sequential criterion for continuity we have a sequence $r_n \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ with $(r_n) \to \sqrt{2}$, but $f(r_n) \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \neq f(\sqrt{2}) = 0$. So my professor was just wrong in this question? Huh..

Comment: Yes. What is true however is that $f(x) \to 0 $ when $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Also, your professor might have been confused with another well known exercise: the map $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{q}$ when $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $q$ minimal in $\mathbb{N}$, is continuous only at irrational numbers.

Comment: I see. That would just be the well-known Thomae's function, right?

Comment: It seems that is its name, I did not know this fact

Comment: Yeah, named after Carl Johannes Thomae. Anyway, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

We have \begin{align}&\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)=\begin{cases}\infty&\text{if }a=0\\ 0&\text{if }a<0\\ \frac1a&\text{if }a>0\end{cases}\\ &\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)=\begin{cases}-\infty&\text{if }a=0\\ \frac1a&\text{if }a<0\\ 0&\text{if }a>0\end{cases}\end{align} Therefore the limit never exists.